# Friendly URLs with WebMatrix and razor

Tags: asp.net, razor, webmatrix

I'm new to ASP.NET and I'm learning first in WebMatrix using razor syntax.

In PHP I used .htaccess to route URLs to database posts, for example:

```
http://mywebsite.com/linux/how-to-install-wamp-in-ubuntu-12.04
```

In that case routes to file:

```
http://mywebsite.com/routes.php?title=how-to-install-wamp-in-ubuntu-12.04
```

I'm trying to route like the PHP example:

```
http://mywebsite.com/routes.cshtml?title=how-to-install-wamp-in-ubuntu-12.04
```

Can I do it in ASP.NET with WebMatrix and razor?

I know how I can take GET data in ASP.NET, but I don't understand how I can make a friendly URL and how I can route to "routes.cshtml" when the page isn't found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Details:** Microsoft is now making this very easy to do for ASP.NET Via a Nuget Package. Unfortunately, this package "Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls" is currently in Pre-Release and WebMatrix doesn't allow you to download Pre-Releases. As a result, following my way of doing it might not be as easy compared to if you just had Visual studio or VS Express.

My suggestion is to download [Visual Studio Express 2012](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx) and either use that for developing or just use it so you can get Nuget Packages.

Ill assume that you want to develop in WebMatrix.

**Solution:**

1. Download and Install Visual Studio Express 2012.
2. Create a new Website
3. In solution Explorer, right click on your Website and select "Manage Nuget Packages.."
4. Press the drop down that says "Stable Only" and choose "Include Prerelease"
5. In the search box enter "Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls"
6. Select "Install"
7. Open your project in Windows Explorer so you can see all the files.
8. Copy the folders "App_Code" and "bin" into your WebMatrix Project (e.g. Add them to your solution).
9. Add a Global Application Class "Global.asax"
10. In the Application_Start method add the following line

    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes);
11. You will now have FriendlyURL's

I know this seems like a lot of work but if you had Visual Studio or WebMatrix allowed Pre-Released then it would be very easy to follow.

**Warning:** If you do decide to develop it in Visual studio delete the following files as the Mobile part of it doesn't work currently (Hence why it is Pre-Release)

- Site.Mobile.Master
- LiSite.Mobile.Master.designer.cs
- ViewSwitcher.ascx
- ViewSwitcher.ascx.designer.cs

**Future:** In the near future there will be release version of FriendlyUrl's and then you will be able to get it from Nuget in WebMatrix much more easier.

**Links To More Information:**

[Information on Microsoft's Friendly Url Package](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx)
[Information on how to use Nuget in WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/how-to-use-nuget-in-webmatrix-2)

Comment: is just what I needed, but I have a question about asp.net ... after I publish the application in a hosting that package will not generate dependency problems?Thanks for the information

Comment: I don't believe this package is intended for the Web Pages framework. It installs Web Forms user controls and Master Pages.

Answer (score 4):

There is an existing package specifically for ASP.NET Web Pages that lets you do what you want and it is available via the WebMatrix Package Manager. It is called Routing For Web Pages. I have written an article on how to use it: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/187/More-Flexible-Routing-For-ASP.NET-Web-Pages

Comment: Oh mike im sorry, i read your comment to late; that is the best solution to my question, but i cant check 2 answers.
Thanks for your article!

Answer (score 0):

of course you can, it is called URL Rewriting

http://developer.mindtouch.com/en/kb/Installing_MindTouch_Core_on_Windows_%28IIS%29/Rewrite_web.config_for_IIS7

or here

http://www.phpgenious.com/2010/04/url-rewriting-with-php-and-iis-7/

or google for more info